# Geometry of Envelope form definition

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, partial-differential-equations

I had read about the envelope of the family of the curve.
It is defined as a curve which is tangent to each member of the family at a single point and it is union of all such points.

To find envelope they had provided condition:

The envelope is the simultaneous solution of following

$F(x,y,t)=0$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}F(x,y,t)=0$

I do not understand how the definition and above conditions are equivalent.

Please Help me.

Any Help will be appreciated.

Comment: [Check this out](http://www.sjsu.edu/faculty/watkins/envelopetheo.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Consider the curve $t\mapsto (x(t),y(t))$ and let's see what are the **necessary** conditions it must fullfil to be an envelope.

> I had read about the envelope of the family of the curve. It is
>   defined as a curve which is tangent to each member of the family at a
>   single point and it is union of all such points.

1. First of all, the curve $t\mapsto (x(t),y(t))$ must have a point of contact with the one-parameter $t$ family of curves implicitly defined by $F(x,y,t)=0$. So you must have $F(x(t),y(t),t)=0$ which is your first equation.
2. Then the curve $t\mapsto (x(t),y(t))$ must be tangent to the curves implicitly defined by $F(x,y,t)=0$.

   On one side, the vector $\left(\begin{array}{c} x'(t^\star) \\ y'(t^\star) \end{array}\right)$ is the tangente direction at $t^\star$ of the curve $t\mapsto (x(t),y(t))$.

   On the other side, for a fixed $t=t^\star$ the vector $\nabla F=\left(\begin{array}{c} \partial_x F \\ \partial_y F  \end{array}\right)$ is a vector **orthogonal** to the tangent of the level-set of $F(x,y,t^\star)=0 $ (if this last point is not clear, you can read  [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/599488/450342))

   Like we want to have an identical tangent direction at point $(x(t^\star),y(t^\star))$ we must impose a zero scalar product
   $$
   \left(\begin{array}{c} x'(t^\star) \\ y'(t^\star) \end{array}\right).\nabla F = 0 = \partial_x F(x(t^\star),y(t^\star),t^\star) x(t^\star)+\partial_y F(x(t^\star),y(t^\star),t^\star) y(t^\star)\ \ \ \ \ (1)
   $$
   However, from point 1/, we also have $F(x(t),y(t),t)=0$, thus $\frac{d}{dt}F(x(t),y(t),t)=0$ which is
   $$
   \partial_x F(x(t^\star),y(t^\star),t^\star) x(t^\star)+\partial_y F(x(t^\star),y(t^\star),t^\star)y(t^\star)+\partial_tF(x(t^\star),y(t^\star),t^\star) = 0\ \ \ \ \ (2)
   $$
   Equations (1) & (2) implies that $\partial_tF(x(t^\star),y(t^\star),t^\star) = 0$

To recap, a necessary condition for $(x(t),y(t))$ being your envelope is that:

- $F(x(t),y(t),t)=0$
- $\partial_t F(x(t),y(t),t)=0$

which is the expected result.